# Tableau Public toolbar not shown in some reports

Tags: tableau-api

Well i'm working in some reports with Tableau Public software.
I'm using the iframe generated to show them in a .net mvc application.

Some works perfectly while others has the toolbar hiddden.

PS: I checked all three options in Toolbar Settings.
Any Help?
And Thanks

Comment: Hi zarzou, can you please include a screenshot?

Comment: Well ty i correct it.It was a hight problem from the iframe.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to fix it on your own. Can you please post your answer and mark it as correct or delete the question so that others don't think you are still looking for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i corrected it.It was a height problem from the iframe.